# Fisher Information of a function of a parameter

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable for which the p.d.f. or the p.f. is $f(x|\theta)$, where the value of the parameter $\theta$ is unknown but must lie in an open interval $\Omega$.  Let $I_0(\theta)$ denote the Fisher information in $X.$  Suppose now that the parameter $\theta$ is replaced by a new parameter $\mu$, where $\theta = \psi(\mu)$ and $\psi$ is a differentiable function.  Let $I_1(\mu)$ denote the Fisher information in $X$ when the parameter is regarded as $\mu.$  Show that $$I_1(\mu) = [\psi'(\mu)]^2 I_0[\psi(\mu)].$$

How would I do this?  Do I need to use a Taylor expansion?  Regardless, I would appreciate a written proof.  This isn't for class but the above statement has been mentioned in texts without any detail whatsoever.

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint**: What's the definition of $I_0(\theta)$? Under standard regularity conditions, what is $\mathbb{E}\big(\frac{\partial \log f(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta}\big)$. Put this together with the chain rule of differentiation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By definition $I_{0}(\theta)=-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d^{2}\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)}{d\theta^{2}}\right].$
So $I_{1}(\mu)=-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d^{2}\log f\left(X\vert\mu\right)}{d\mu^{2}}\right]$.By
the chain rule we have 
$$I_{1}\left(\mu\right) =  -\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d^{2}\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)}{d\theta^{2}}\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\mu}\right)^{2}+\frac{d\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)}{d\theta}\frac{d^{2}\theta}{d\mu^{2}}\right]$$
      $$=  -\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d^{2}\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)}{d\theta^{2}}\right]\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\mu}\right)^{2}+\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)}{d\theta}\right]\frac{d^{2}\theta}{d\mu^{2}}. $$

But $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{d\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)}{d\theta}\right]=0.$  So we get
$$
I_{1}\left(\mu\right)=I_{0}\left(\theta\right)\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\mu}\right)^{2}.$$

Comment: Can you explain how you're using the chain rule?  Which functions are involved?

Comment: The functions involved are $\frac{d}{d\theta}\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)$ and $\frac{d\theta}{d\mu}$ It is a product and you differentiating wrt $\mu$

Comment: NB: $\frac{d^{2}\log f\left(X\vert\mu\right)}{d\mu^{2}}=\frac{d}{d\mu}\left[\frac{d}{d\mu}\log f\left(X\vert\mu\right)\right]=\frac{d}{d\mu}\left[\frac{d}{d\theta}\log f\left(X\vert\theta\right)\cdot\frac{d\theta}{d\mu}\right]$

Comment: Where does [d logf(X|θ) / dθ] = 0 come from?

Comment: I think the chain rule in the comment to this answer by @Nana is incorrect.
It should be $\frac{d}{d\mu}logf(X|\theta)$ in the left bracket.